# AttributeError: module 'ray.rllib.algorithms.ppo' has no attribute 'DEFAULT_CONFIG'

Tags: python, attributeerror, ray

When running software on Python 3.8.16, I had to change "ray.rllib.agents.ppo" into "ray.rllib.algorithms.ppo". Now it throws:
AttributeError: module 'ray.rllib.algorithms.ppo' has no attribute 'DEFAULT_CONFIG'.

How this issue can be approached?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the `ray.rllib.algorithms.ppo.ppo.PPOConfig` class instead.

Fortunately, the [Ray RLlib documentation](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/rllib/rllib-algorithms.html#ray.rllib.algorithms.ppo.ppo.PPOConfig) has examples that you can refer to. I've pasted them here as well:

```py
from ray.rllib.algorithms.ppo import PPOConfig
config = PPOConfig()  
config = config.training(gamma=0.9, lr=0.01, kl_coeff=0.3)  
config = config.resources(num_gpus=0)  
config = config.rollouts(num_rollout_workers=4)  
print(config.to_dict())  
# Build a Algorithm object from the config and run 1 training iteration.
algo = config.build(env="CartPole-v1")  
algo.train()
```

```py
from ray.rllib.algorithms.ppo import PPOConfig
from ray import air
from ray import tune
config = PPOConfig()
# Print out some default values.
print(config.clip_param)  
# Update the config object.
config.training(  
lr=tune.grid_search([0.001, 0.0001]), clip_param=0.2
)
# Set the config object's env.
config = config.environment(env="CartPole-v1")   
# Use to_dict() to get the old-style python config dict
# when running with tune.
tune.Tuner(  
    "PPO",
    run_config=air.RunConfig(stop={"episode_reward_mean": 200}),
    param_space=config.to_dict(),
).fit()
```